# LWC Lookup Filter based on Account Lookup

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am looking for a way to limit the contact lookup field to only contacts that are associated with that account. I need the same thing for the asset, but what I get for contact I can make work for the asset.

So basic HTML structure:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form recor-id={recordId}
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AssetId" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <template if:false={showAddContact}>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="ContactId" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </template>
            </div>
         </div>
```

How do I get the contact lookup to only show what is associated with that account?

--------------------- UPDATED --------------------------

LookupController Class
I have attempted to put in the AccountId but nothing seems to work with the variable. If I hardcode the contacts get pulled up.

The second part of this is I can't figure out how to pass in the new array of contacts to a lookup component so the user can search out of those specific contacts.

```
public with sharing class LookupController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Object> getRecordsByName(String objectName, String searchFor, String accountId) {
        String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM ';
        queryString += String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName) + ' WHERE Name Like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchFor) + '%\'' + ' AND AccountId = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountId) + '\'';
        return Database.query(queryString);
    }
}
```

JS Code

```
    @wire(getContactRecords, { searchKey: '$searchKey', accountId: '$accountId'})
    contacts;

    handleOnLoad(event) {
       if (this.loadedForm == false) {
            this.accountId = this.record.data.fields.AccountId.value;

            if (this.accountId != null) {
                this.contact = {Name : event.detail.Name, Id: event.detail.Id, accountId: this.accountId}
            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using the single form here without an ID being saved on the record. This is assuming that there is a filter set on the ContactId field to filter where `AccountId == (your record).AccountId`. These filters will not apply on the `lightning-record-edit-form` | `lightning-record-form` prior to the value being present on the record being presented on the form. You will need to do something custom for those cases to return the filtered list for selection, possibly a custom search component who's return value will be applied to the value on the form.

simple solution would be to make the custom search component, set the value in your controller via `CustomEvent` and use that value to populate your `ContactId` field. Your field will be able to see the value if you do this:

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="ContactId" value={jsValue} ></lightning-input-field>
```

in your JS:

```
@track jsValue;

handleSetMyJsValue( event ){
   this.jsValue = event && event.detail && event.detail.value;
}
```

Event in custom component:

```
this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'completed', {
   bubbles: false,
   cancelable : false,
   detail: {
     value: "some value you selected in your search..."
   }
});
```

then just set the `oncompleted={handleSetMyJsValue}` wherever you use that component on your form. and you would render your custom component and `lightning-input-field` based on that value.

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="ContactId" if:true={jsValue} value={jsValue} ></lightning-input-field>

<c-some-custom-search-component if:false={jsValue} oncompleted={handleSetMyJsValue} filter-id={myAccountId} ></c-some-custom-search-component>
```

How you pursue building that component is on you. but i have done similar for this same case in the past and this has worked out to set a value based on those filters. You can supply the Id from the account field to filter and store it on the other component to help your filter and then use a `wire` search to get your results.

All in all, you have some work ahead of you to get that to filter without having custom lookup filters in place, and also for cases where the record hasn't a value yet stored. You would not want to have your users save more than 1 time to set the value, so this would solve that case for you as well.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ronnie,
Would we not be able to achieve this through a class? I have updated my code to reflect LookupControler class that I have seen before. The hardest thing to find online is a working custom lookup that can be manipulated.

Comment: wouldn't be able to do in a class as the lookup in the form is using the record form which is communicating with the uiRecordApi so it will need to have a value set to use the lookup filters accordingly

Comment: Ronnie, I will attempt this article. Unfortunately, it was written for Aura and I will need it in lightning.

Comment: the one i sent to you was written in LWC, not based in Aura. he did include at the end an aura wrapper, but the core component is in LWC

Comment: So I am adding to the existing HTML Like
```<c-customlookup iconname="standard:case" objectname="Case" searchfield="CaseNumber"></c-customlookup>```
and getting this error. Failed to resolve entry for module "customLookup"

I have deployed all the other components first

Comment: did you create the other module yet?

Comment: I verbatim copied the components and created them with the exact names. I will push to a temp repo fo you to look at.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll take a look at them this evening after I've finished off work. 

Comment: Here is the Git repo https://github.com/AndyHaas/editCase

Comment: try `c-custom-lookup` instead. I notice you have the component named "customLookup"
the camel casing would split the words with a `-` as it is being used on your template. All words will be lower cased on the tag

Comment: it will be case sensitive so that is important to know. if you named it `customlookup` then you could access it as `c-customlookup` in your LWC template. i see your template has `c-CustomLookup` and that would never be found. so def `c-custom-lookup` will be the accessor you need

Comment: the same will go for all attributes in your tag. `@api` attributes that are camel cased will be split by a `-` and converted to lower case inside the tag to access them. So if you had `searchfield` camel cased to `searchField` it's accessor in your tag will be `search-field`

Comment: since the component you copied has an event named `selectedrec` you would then access it to be `onselectedrec={replaceWithMyEventHandlerHereFromMainComponent}` and use your handler in your parent component to set the value from the result using `event.detail.recordId` to get the value

Comment: c-custom-lookup was correct. I thought I tried that but I guess I might have left a capital letter. I have updated the parameters in that also. And which component are you referring to for ```selectedrec```

Comment: https://github.com/AndyHaas/editCase/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/customLookup/customLookup.js Line 53. the event name is what you should be listening for. note that the same event is listed on line 69 when the value is cleared.

Comment: you can even hide the `lightning-input-field` on your page by applying a style class and specifying it in a css file on your component with `display: none` and submitting the form will take in the value set to the field that you apply through your variable listed in the `value` field of an input field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106308/discussion-between-ronnie-and-gunner1714).