# record type for lookup field in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have an lwc component with AccountID lookup from contact object.
Now, this lookup fetches account records when searched with any value. Below is my html markup:

```
<lightning:record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">         
                    <lightning-input-field label= "Account Name" field-name="AccountId"></lightning-input-field>
                </lightning:record-edit-form>
```

Now, as per my requirement, only one specific record type records should be fetched from the lookup. The record type name is 'Customer Service Records' and only this records should be fetched from that Account Name lookup field in my lwc.

Is there any way to limit the search only for this specific record type records. Please suggest

Comment: u can follow the link below, that might kidda help you. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300822/lwc-lookup-filter-based-on-account-lookup

Comment: @mdanish9, from the given link, I understood that we need to go for custom search lwc component to add filters instead of going in the standard manner above. Is there any way to do it using standard markup?